# Translating Python np.expand_dims to R

Tags: python, r, numpy

I am currently translating some Python code to R.

I have a hard time understanding how np.expand_dims works and how to translate it into R.

For exemple, I have the following codes in Python :

```
y = np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 1, size = (n, m))
y1 = np.expand_dims(Y, 0)
y2 = np.expand_dims(Y, 1) 
y3 = np.expand_dims(Y, 2)
```

What does that code do ? Say we have the following code in R, what would be an equivalent R code ?

```
y = matrix(rnorm(n*m),n,m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python function from **numpy** allows one to expand the axis of an array. You can replicate it in R using the package **listarrays** which you can find on [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/listarrays/index.html).

The function you want to look is `expand_dims()`. Please, refer to page 6 of the reference manual which you can find [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/listarrays/listarrays.pdf).

Also, since you want to manipulate arrays, there is the specific class `array` in R which is not a `matrix` technically. The objective is to modify the shape of your input array.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure what do you mean by "allows one to expand the axis of an array" (which is a bit tautological given the name of the function)... Also, any way to do something equivalent in base R ? I am not very fond of installing packages for what seems like algebra.

Comment: Expand the axis means you add a dimension to your array. Python calls it shape. If you don't want to install another package, which is just a data manipulation package and not one that deals with linear algebra, then you can copy-paste the code and define your own function. The working principle is that you don't want to work with matrices like you were doing but with arrays.

Comment: Ok, say I start with an (n,m) dimensioned array. As I understand It, the three lines of code should give me three different arrays of dimensions (d,n,m), (n,d,m) and (n,m,d) respectively. What is d in python ? How are the values filled ?

Comment: I have accepted your answer as your solution seems to give a similar result than in Python. My problem  in fact appears subsequently and seems to be linked to how R handle arrays after the dimension expansion. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61481779/difference-between-r-and-python-in-handling-basic-arrays-operations